# My shield disappeared during my jailbreak!

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I got arrested for stealing in the town of Didenhil in *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning* and I then went and escaped from jail. After grabbing my equipment I ran out of town and did some other stuff. However I noticed that after all this happened that my shield (a very nice kite shield with a def of +100 and some powerful gems I socketed in it) was missing!! Any idea what happened to it?

Comment: Are you sure your shield wasn't stolen from someplace? AFAIK all stolen items are removed when you are sent to jail.

Comment: It could have been, where would it have gone? Back to the owner?

Comment: @RHINO_Mk.II Hmm, my `Chilled Faeblades`, which I know were stolen, also went away making me think you are right.

Comment: @Cyber: Might be worth checking out (on another game).

Comment: @JeffMercado I wouldn't even be asking if I had a save to revert to.

Comment: @Cyber: You saying to deleted the "tutorial completed" save?  That would have been a great place to start.  (I'd do it myself but I can't play at the moment)

Comment: @JeffMercado That save is some 30 hours ago. ;)

Comment: @Cyber: I'm just saying you could use that save to get to the first town, steal something, equip it, get arrested and see what happens to test that theory.  That ought to take maybe 15-20 minutes.

Comment: @JeffMercado Ah. Will try.

Comment: @CyberSkull That's why i always quick save before doing something stupid ^_^

Comment: I just confirmed that stolen items are confiscated. There is a trick to laundering items: Take your stolen goods to a fence, sell them, then immediately buy them back for the sale price and you will have "clean" items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have no doubt read from the comments on other answers and on the question itself, stolen goods are lost when you get arrested. **Anything that you stole in *Kingdoms of Amalur: The Reckoning* is lost if it is in your possession when you are arrested.** If it was stolen (little red hand beside it), your shield actually disappeared during arrest, rather than jailbreak and I believe it is unrecoverable. You can check with the NPC you stole it from and/or their lootable chests and dressers, but as NPC loot is generated on first loot and regenerates after a time, while lootables stay looted forever, I highly doubt that your exact shield will be there. In short, if you don't have a save to recover to, your shield is lost forever. The game should have auto-saved at some point around then - hopefully you didn't overwrite it.

All non-stolen items confiscated from you upon arrest are held in a treasure chest within the jail, but as you've said you recovered your equipment, you've already encountered this chest.

**Deductively, barring a defect in the game whereupon your shield was accidentally destroyed, your shield must have been a stolen item and is thus unrecoverable.**

### Stolen Item Insurance

To avoid this problem in the future, there's an easy solution to preserving stolen items. You could not steal, but where's the fun in that? The easier solution it to make your stolen items not be stolen items. **If you sell a stolen item to a fence in a Traveler camp or to any merchant if your mercantile skill is maxed and then purchase the item back from them, it will no longer be a stolen item** and thus won't be lost upon arrest. I suggest you do this before socketing awesome gems so as to reduce the cost to you.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually stumbled onto the laundering thing. All my possessions have been laundered through The Travelers.

Answer (score 1):

Stolen goods in the Gorhart jail are easy to find. It stands to reason that stolen goods would be available to you in other jails as well, though it may take more hunting.

I wouldn't know about other jails, as these days when "arrested" I simply dump a bucket of stolen riches on the lad's head and tell him to go away. I recommend you do the same, Dove.

Answer (score 0):

If your shield was an item that you stole, it will have been confiscated when you were sent to jail. Apparently, items that are confiscated in this manner can be found in a chest somewhere in or around the jail, although I haven't found any concrete evidence to support this.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking about Skyrim?

Comment: Stolen goods are confiscated in Kingdoms of Amalur as well.